# Adminarea Text Edit

Tags: php, text, admin, edit

I am looking for a codesnippet/github project or simular which provides "text-edit-functionalities" for an admin panel simular to wordpress or the stackoverflow "ask question".

It should provide basic function for the user like making a text bold, adding a bulleted list, adding pictures, etc and on the other hand convert the text to html.

I search a lot for such a project but couldnt find one written in php.

I would be glad if someone would know a decent project which fulfills my needs.

Comment: Google for **BBCode**

Comment: Look at [scribe by the guardian](https://github.com/guardian/scribe), or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), or a good bootstrap one is [summernote](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/). Obviously there are loads more

Comment: I like Markdown, just search for "Markdown Wysiwyg" on google or github and you will find what you want. Never tried this one, but it looks like it match your needs: https://stackedit.io/ - There is a PHP Parser to that can generate your HTML http://parsedown.org/

Comment: thank you all, summernote looks perfekt!